# How can I store the digits of two numbers in an array like in the code below, without using a string?

Tags: c++, console-application

I need a program to read two numbers and store these number's digits in an array with a ';' in between them. I tried it using a char array but it didn't seem to work for me, and I also tried, as you can see below, by storing the numbers in a string first and putting a ';' in between then storing them in the array. How can I do that without the string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char v[99999];
    string numTotal;
    cin>>a>>b;
    numTotal=to_string(a)+';'+to_string(b);
    for(int i=0;i<numTotal.length();i++){
        v[i]=numTotal[i];
        cout<<v[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a function that's called getline(std::cin,) ( as long as you don't press a specific keyword like: Enter or sth) it will take your string all at once ( you can write 3;4 or sth and it will store it word-by-word).

```
getline(cin,numTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

string is simplest way, but if you dont want to use string, you can use std::stack like this

```
int main() {
    int a, b, n;
    cin >> a >> b;
    stack<int> aStack;
    n = a;
    while(n > 0) {
        aStack.push(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    stack<int> bStack;
    n = b;
    while(n > 0) {
        bStack.push(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    while(!aStack.empty()) {
        cout << aStack.top() << ' ';
        aStack.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
    while(!bStack.empty()) {
        cout << bStack.top() << ' ';
        bStack.pop();
    }
}
```